# Change avatar size Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I want to change the size of the profile photo when the photo is a gif, how can I do it?

I have tried `user.displayAvatarURL ({size: 2048, dynamic: true});` but the bot crashes D:

the error is the following:: `(node:15836) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: user.displayAvatarURL is not a function`

```js
module.exports = {
    nombre: "avatar",
    alias: ["foto"],
    descripcion: "Este comando muestra la foto de perfil de un usuario",
    run: (client, message, args) => {

        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        const avatarEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            avatarEmbed.setColor(0x333333)
            avatarEmbed.setAuthor(user.username)
            avatarEmbed.setImage(user.displayAvatarURL);
        message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);

    }
}
```

Comment: If the bot crashes you get an error. Please include that here so we can help you.

Comment: You are right haha, the error is the following: ```(node:15836) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: user.displayAvatarURL is not a function```

Comment: well, there you have it. `displayAvatarURL` is not a function. In this case it's meant literally. Change it to `displayAvatarURL()`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to fix the crash, I attach code :D

```js
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        if(user.displayAvatarURL.endsWith(".gif")){
            const avatarEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            avatarEmbed.setColor(0x333333)
            avatarEmbed.setAuthor(user.username)
            avatarEmbed.setImage(user.displayAvatarURL + "?size=1024");
            message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);
        } else {
            const avatarEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            avatarEmbed.setColor(0x333333)
            avatarEmbed.setAuthor(user.username)
            avatarEmbed.setImage(user.displayAvatarURL);
            message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);
        }
```